# WIFI driver for MacBook Pro will be disabled after restart

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, macbook-pro

I found a way to install WIFI driver for my MacBook Pro mid 2014. Unfortunately after restarting it's wifi will be disabled. I installed the driver through this way:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --reinstall install bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb wl brcmfmac brcmsmac bcma
sudo modprobe wl
```

Comment: Did you actually install to a hard drive, or is this an ISO or persistent install?

Comment: I installed that through ISO on its SSD drive @guiverc

Comment: Please add the version of Ubuntu and the kernel you are using to the question with edit. Do not answer in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded from Ubuntu 23 to 22, and the problem was resolved.

Comment: So you downgraded from a version that does not exist to Ubuntu Core 22. Exact info is needed.